# jmx mbean thread safety

Tags: java, jmx

if i have a class, that is also a mbean, and i use functions of the class in my code, in only one thread, and also call a function by jmx, should i synchronize that code? thanks

Answer (score 5):

The code should be thread-safe, yes. If you choose to make it thread-safe using `synchronized`, then that's up to you.

MBeans that are invoked via JMX will be invoked by the container, using its own threads, separate from your own code's threads.